# User interaction without login Angular?

Tags: javascript, java, html, angular, cookies

On my website there are users and guests, and I want both to be able to "like" elements on my website. For the users it’s not a problem to check if they already "liked" a specific element to prevent them from giving another "like" to the same element, but I am not sure about how to check if the guest "liked" an element to prevent multiple likes from one specific guest. I am using Angular and I thought about saving such info with cookies, but I don’t know how yet, and if it will be trusted enough or not. Any ideas on how to implement them? Thanks.

Comment: A cookie is not a reliable solution, they can be easily deleted.

Comment: any other solution ? @JoH

Comment: I'm afraid there's no solution, you can't rely on cookies, nor on localStorage, on any solution that involve on storing something on the user's computer. I think you have to give the right to like something only for logged users.

Comment: You should not store these on client side. One can simply open the site in Incognito multiple times and keep liking it. That is the reason many websites ask to login for such features.

Answer (score 0):

Best way use **localStorage** , to be more complex use Hush (value and key ) in localStorage .

> HTML

```
<button type="button" (click)="liked()">
          <span *ngIf="!unlike">like</span>
          <span *ngIf="unlike">unlike</span>
          {{like}}
</button>
```

> TS

```
like=99
unlike:Boolean=true

liked(){
 if(localStorage.getItem('like') == null){
 localStorage.setItem('like','true')
  this.like=this.like+1;
  this.unlike =!this.unlike
  
}else{
  localStorage.removeItem('like')
  this.like=this.like-1
  this.unlike =!this.unlike
}

}
```

```
like=99;
ipActionLike =['1','2'] ;
unlike:Boolean=true;

liked(){
//get information browser user ip 
 if(localStorage.getItem('like') == null){
   for (var i = 0; i <this.ipActionLike.length; i++) { 
      if (this.itemArray[i] == ipUser) { 
          //remove ipUser from array
           localStorage.removeItem('like');
           this.like=this.like-1;
           this.unlike =!this.unlike; } 
      else{
          //push ipUser to array
          localStorage.setItem('like','true')
           this.like=this.like+1;
            this.unlike =!this.unlike }
  }

}
  
}else{
   //push ipUser to array
  localStorage.removeItem('like')
  this.like=this.like-1
  this.unlike =!this.unlike
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your help, but wouldn't it be very easy for the user to delete from LocalStorage in case he wants?and then the likes amount won't be trusted enough.

Comment: Very easy for the user to delete from `LocalStorage` in case he wants ,Maybe the user doesn't know this for a lot of reliability. Use the second solution , Solution is updated, click the checkmark (✓) to accept it. @user3469465